# Detecting the frame of a key release

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I'm trying to get it to detect when a key is switched between the down state and the up state. I need it to display that the key is released for one frame before reverting to the UP state.

I can add more information or code if needed. Thank you in advance.

```
package engine 
{
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;


/**
 *  Input Manager
 */
public class Input 
{
    static private const UP         : uint = 0;
    static private const PRESS      : uint = 1;
    static private const HELD       : uint = 2;
    static private const END_PRESS  : uint = 3;

    static private const START_PRESS:uint = 9999;


    static private var keys     : Vector.<uint>;
    static private var active   : Vector.<KeyState>;



    static public function init( stage:Stage ):void 
    {
        stage.removeEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown );
        stage.removeEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,   onKeyUp );   

        keys    = new Vector.<uint>(255);   // state of all keys
        active  = new Vector.<KeyState>();      // only keys in a state other than up
        //time    = new Vector.<Time>();

        stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown );
        stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,   onKeyUp );  
    }


    /// Flash Event: A key was just pressed
    static public function onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
    {
        // If the system is sending another key down event, but the key is marked
        // as being in some other state than down; ignore it.
        if ( keys[ e.keyCode ] != UP )
            return;

        keys[ e.keyCode ] = START_PRESS;

        var keyState:KeyState = new KeyState( e.keyCode, Time.frameCount );
        active.push( keyState );
    }

    /// Flash Event: A key was raised
    static public function onKeyUp( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
    {

        keys[ e.keyCode ] = UP

        // Loop through all active keys; there is a slight chance that
        // more than one entry for a key being "down" snuck in due to
        // how Flash / OS handles input.
        var keyState:KeyState;
        for ( var i:int = active.length - 1; i > -1; i-- )
        {

            keyState = active[i];               // get next keystate in active list
            if ( keyState.code == e.keyCode )   // if the code matches
                active.splice( i, 1 );          // remove
        }
    }

    /// Call this once per frame
    static public function update():void
    {
        var code    :uint;
        var keyState:KeyState;

        // Go through all the inputs currently mark as being active...
        for ( var i:int = active.length - 1; i > -1; i-- )
        {
            keyState = active[i];
            code = keyState.code;

            // If a key is pressed and it's the frame after it was pressed,
            // change the state.
            if ( keys[code] == PRESS && keyState.frame < Time.frameCount )
            {
                keys[code] = HELD;
                continue;
            }

            // If a press is just starting, mark it as started and update
            // the frame for the press to be this frame.
            if ( keys[code] == START_PRESS )
            {
                keys[code] = PRESS;
                keyState.frame = Time.frameCount;
            }

        }

    }

    /// Has a key just been pressed in this frame?
    static public function getKeyDown( code:uint ):Boolean
    {
        return keys[ code ] == PRESS;
    }

    /// Is a key in state other than being "up"?
    static public function getKey( code:uint ):Boolean
    {
        return keys[ code ] == HELD;
    }

    static public function getKeyRelease( code:uint ):Boolean
    {
        return keys[ code ] == END_PRESS;
    }
}
}


internal class KeyState
{
public var code :uint;
public var frame:uint;

/// CTOR
function KeyState( code:uint, frame:uint ) :void
{
    this.code   = code;
    this.frame  = frame;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're question is, I understand what you're trying to accomplish but you didn't really state what is going wrong for you, have you been debugging do you get any breakpoints to hit, do you get an error?  Not sure where to start with just the bit of code.

Comment: If you want to know the number of current frame, just add a `private var current_frame:int = 0;` and in enterFrame listener: `current_frame++;`

Answer (score 0):

Because you want something to be done within frames, you have to use Event.ENTER_FRAME listener. This way you'll be able to reset "just released" keys to "up" state correctly. In this case, you do:

```
static public function onKeyUp( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    keys[ e.keyCode ] = END_PRESS;
    // I'm not sure why you need other checks in here, add them if you like
}

static public function onEnterFrame( e:Event ):void
{
    for (var i:int=keys.length-1; i>=0;i--) if (keys[i]==END_PRESS) {
        keys[i]=UP;
        // do whatever you need with i'th key, as this will be the "just released" key.
    }
}
```

Update: you already have a rudimentary enter-frame procedure, and you already have some of the mechanics about press and held states, so you can plainly add this cycle into that procedure.